# Why is my React app not rendering?

Tags: reactjs

I have a basic HTML/ JS project and have been trying to get react to run. For various reasons, I need to run install React from existing project and not from `create-react-app`.

Project directory:

```
|-node_modules
|
|- public
|     |- js
|     |  |- index.js
|     |
|     |- index.html
|
|- package.json
|
| - ...
```

Inside `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
 );
```

Inside `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

inside `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "developer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "http-server": "^0.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "15.6.1"
  }
}
```

Super basic. I am following instruction from [FB React Installation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html). However, when I ran `npm start` and went to `8080`, it shows a completely blank page.

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to compile this js code into ES5 code. If you see your console there must be some errors

Comment: Sorry, super newb question. How can I compile it into ES5? I am on http://babeljs.io/ and there are different configurations. I am not sure which one to install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simplest implementation of react without bundle setup.

From documentation itself: [single-file-example.html](http://view-source:https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads/single-file-example.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) with [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) to set up your react development environment. [This](https://medium.com/@fastlane80/setup-react-js-with-npm-babel-6-and-webpack-in-under-1-hour-1a714f973506) has great explanation to things and getting started.

Also you can use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) to get started with your project and all the settings will be done before hand.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a webpack or browserify to render into a browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react  tag is not HTML tag but it is react html tag:

h1 : React.HTMLProps

So, it will not render as HTML. This react html is called as JSX. 
Browser don't understand JSX you need a parser for it. To parse this JSX you may use babel.

** All html tags in react are bot actual html tags but react's tags

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to nest the content in a return function in your component.